# NameError: uninitialized contant CONFIG when running rake db:create (YAML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, yaml

I'm trying to get a local instance of an application running, and I keep getting

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CONFIG
```

when I run `bundle exec rake db:setup`.

Here's what `CONFIG` looks like in my environment.rb file:

```
CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read('/etc/twkeys/university/course_scheduler/config.yml')).freeze
```

When I test the above in the console, I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant YAML
```

If I run `require 'yaml'` in the console, and then run the above again, `CONFIG` seems to initialize ok.

I've tried putting `require 'yaml'` in environment.rb and other various config files with no luck.

Comment: do you need it in your environment.rb file ?, if not, put that line in a file in the config/initializers/ folder.

Comment: @fanta thanks. i've tried putting it in environment.rb as well as in application.rb, and every file in config/initializers/ that mentions CONFIG

Comment: ohh, so, you need the CONFIG constant in your initializer files ?, then try putting that line in an initializer file that's the first one on that folder, let's say you name that file as 00_config_initializer.rb, so that it runs before all the other initializer files where that constant is needed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @fanta still getting the same error though :/

Answer (score 0):

This is because `environment.rb` file is not loaded from Rake tasks. You can easily trace it by looking in the `Rakefile`. It loads `config/application` file and not `config/environment`. There is no need to initialize application to perform Rake task.

The easiest solution is to move `CONFIG` constant to the `config/application` file under the module (remember that namespace may be needed for using it in other places).